# Multi-statement SQL returning zero records with Python and MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have the following SQL query that works fine in Workbench but when using the MySql connector in Python 3.x I get a `null` result:

```
sql = "SET @v1 = (SELECT cost FROM sales ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 4,1); \
        SET @v2 = (SELECT AVG(cost) FROM \
        (SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3) AS t); \
        SET @v3 = ((@v1 - @v2) / ((@v1 + @v2) / 2)) * 100; \
        SELECT \
            ROUND(@v1) as `20days`, \
            ROUND(@v2) as `15days`, \
            ROUND(@v2 - @v1) as diff, \
            ROUND(@v3,2) as percent, \
            @v2 > @v1 as improving;"

con = get_db()
cur = con.cursor(dictionary=True)
cur.execute(sql, multi=True)
```

The `get_db` function works fine, I have other queries using it. Here is the output from Workbench:

```
20days  15days  diff    percent improving
5574418 5611906 37488   -0.67   1
```

Any pointers as to why I am getting an empty result would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

When you use multi-statement, the execute() function returns a set of results, and you have to loop over these results before you can fetch rows from them. Your code is only processing the first result, a `SET` statement, which has no rows to return.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html shows how to do it:

```
operation = 'SELECT 1; INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (); SELECT 2'
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
  if result.with_rows:
    print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
      result.statement))
    print(result.fetchall())
  else:
    print("Number of rows affected by statement '{}': {}".format(
      result.statement, result.rowcount))
```

This shows how to loop over the multiple results, check if each has any rows to return, and then fetch the rows from the respective result.

But why add this complex code trying to do multi-statement, when it's easier to execute one at a time, get the basic values from SQL, and then do your calculations in Python?

I haven't tested the following, but it should illustrate what I mean:

```
sqlV1 = "SELECT cost FROM sales ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 4,1)"
sqlV2 = "SELECT AVG(cost) AS cost FROM \
        (SELECT * FROM sales ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 3) AS t)"

con = get_db()
cur = con.cursor(dictionary=True)
cur.execute(sqlV1)
v1row = cursor.fetchone() 
cur.execute(sqlV2)
v2row = cursor.fetchone()

cost20days = round(v1row["cost"])
cost15days = round(v2row["cost"])
costDiff = round(v2row["cost"] - v1row["cost"])
costPercent = round((v1row["cost"]-v2row["cost"]) / ((v1row["cost"]+v2row["cost"])/2)) * 100, 2)
improving = (v2row["cost"] > v1row["cost"])
```